# Stacking jQuery Events (Animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am trying to animate an element, then when the animation is over, add a class:

```
                $(this).animate({ width: "1em" }, 500);
                $(this).addClass("hidden");
```

However the addClass happens right away.

Is there a way to say, "Wait till Animation is done" ?

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a callback function in animate:

```
 $(this).animate({ width: "1em" }, 500, function(){
      $(this).addClass("hidden");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).animate({ width: "1em" }, 500, function(e){

   // Animation complete.
   $(e).addClass("hidden");
  });
);
```

A callback function is what you want.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function, like so:

```
(function(elm){
    $(elm).animate({width: "1em"}, 500, function(){ 
        $(elm).addClass("hidden");
    });
})($(this));
```

The outer function call is to make sure that the proper element is called when the addClass event is called by binding the element to the function, rather than relying on `this`.

The other solutions can and will work in most cases, however, this extra bit just makes sure that the right element is always targeted in the callback function.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Loy63t/)